# How to install Crystal Reports without Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports, installation

I am new to Crystal report and I am trying to install it so I can use it.

Is there any way to install Crystal Reports without having Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You may install the stand-alone version. But You will not able to use it since it uses Visual Studio Interface. You can install the Crystal Reports Viewer only.

> Note 1: To integrate "SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio" into VS 2010 or 2012 (SP 7 and higher) or VS 2013 (SP 9 or higher) or VS 2015 RC (SP14) - VS 2015 (fully - SP 15), you must run the Install Executable. Running the MSI will not fully integrate Crystal Reports into VS. MSI files by definition are for runtime distribution only.
>   By default Windows 10 does not install the 3.5 framework, CR for VS still needs it. Select it by "Turn Windows feature on or off" and choose both options.
>
> Note 2: SAP Crystal Reports, Developer Version for Visual Studio .NET does NOT support Express Editions of any version of Visual Studio .NET. VS.

You can download all versions from: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

Comment: Thanks a lot. But, I need to use it. One more thing, I downloaded the whole package for eclipse, but it does not work. Can I have all the features of Crystal report in eclipse?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Everything developed for Eclipse are only Plugins and not the Full Applications, so some of modules are only for VS and Windows.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to develop a new crystal report, then you can use Developer Edition from the below link. In developer edition .exe, you require Visual Studio.

And, if you want to run crystal report on release mode without installing visual studio for the client, then you can use .msi file of crystal report runtime from this site. This file does not require an install of Visual Studio.

You can download this from following link.

https://www.tektutorialshub.com/crystal-reports/how-to-download-and-install-crystal-report-runtime/